# How can I store the output of two loops into one variable?

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website to get a name model and price for it. With these two loops, I get just two lists of names of devices and prices of the devices.

```
(Name Model)
(Price)
```

How can I combine these two loops to get this info in one string? For example: Model name + Price?

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    for price in soup.find_all('span', class_='b-product-gallery__price'):
        modelPrice = price.text
        print(modelPrice)

    for name in soup.find_all('a', class_='b-product-gallery__title'):
        modelName = name.text
        print(modelName)
main()
```

Comment: Are they guaranteed to be of the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip the two scrape results and iterate through them both at the same time using `zip`. Note that if one of the results is shorter than the other, the longer result will be truncated to match the length of the shorter result, and therefore you will lose data.

```
def main():
    prices = soup.find_all('span', class_='b-product-gallery__price')
    names = soup.find_all('a', class_='b-product-gallery__title')
    for price, name in zip(prices, names):
        modelPrice = price.text
        modelName = name.text
        print(modelPrice, modelName)

main()
```